# android, automatic push update data for apps

Tags: android, server-push

I want to push new data to the apps on user's device after a couple of days, like news update service. It's NOT APK update. Where do I get some clues to start with? tks in advance

(sorry if this question is dumb, but why can't I search for it on stackoverflow, I must miss something?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this in many different ways. One option is to design your app to periodically query a server-side [REST API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) and download new information in an JSON/XML format. That information can be stored in a local SQLite or flat file database on the device. You could also integrate with [Google's Cloud Messaging](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/index.html) service to send push notifications to the device. When your application receives a push message it could spawn a new background process to download any updated content from your server.

Answer (score 0):

You can use push notification (search for c2dm) which will notify users whenever, content/data is updated on server. Whenever, android application will receive push message from server, it will update the local database (say, news database in your case) from server.

Hope it is helpful information for you.

Answer (score -2):

Just upload the new app, with the same key that you used it previously and also increment the version code.

Comment: sorry but your answer is irrelevant, I stated specifically that it is not APK update, I want to push some data.